# Can I get current location from LocationManager if not calling startUpdatingLocation?

Tags: swift, locationmanager

As subject says, I wanna get current location by below code when view appears without calling startUpdatingLocation. Is that possible?

```
curLocation = locationManager.location
```

My running app will call startUpdatingLocation when start running, so I don't want to call it at view appear method.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after but you can use requestLocation() to get the current location one time. It will call locationmgr(didUpdateLocations) with the result.

Comment: I don't want to call didUpdateLocations, but it seems I have to.

Comment: You can call stopUpdatingLocation inside didUpdateLocations to keep more of an on demand approach.

Comment: I don't think there's any other choice for core location. You either use start/stop or request (or both).

Comment: Ok, I tried use start to get location, then stop updating location. Works fine, thanks a lot!